# How to transform currentTimeMillis to a readable date format?

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, time

I want to use `currentTimeMillis` twice so I can calculate a duration but I also want to display Time and Date in user readable format. I'm having trouble as `currentTimeMillis` is good for the calculation but I can't see a built in function to convert to nice time or time/date.

I use

```
android.text.format.DateFormat df = new android.text.format.DateFormat();
df.format("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss", new java.util.Date());
```

for producing nice time and date and what I'd ultimately like to do is show my resulting `currentTimeMillis` value into the  `android.text.format.DateFormat df = new android.text.format.DateFormat();`

e.g.

```
android.text.format.DateFormat df = currentTimeMillis();
```

when I try I get

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to DateFormat

I've tried to use some casting but can't see how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

It will work.

```
long yourmilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm");    
Date resultdate = new Date(yourmilliseconds);
System.out.println(sdf.format(resultdate));
```

Comment: thanks thought there would be something, but its likely to be easier to find a pin in a haystack!  cheers.

Comment: Thanks, was dealing with a pesky problem and tried solving on my own, making the date readable made it so much simpler to solve my problem.

Answer (score 49):

**There is a simpler way in Android**

```
 DateFormat.getInstance().format(currentTimeMillis);
```

Moreover, Date is deprecated, so use [DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html) class.

```
   DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date(0));  
   DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date(0));  
   DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date(0));
```

The above three lines will give:

```
Dec 31, 1969  
Dec 31, 1969 4:00:00 PM  
4:00:00 PM  12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: Aren't you using a deprecated constructor when you call `new Date(0)`?

Comment: Just checked.. I dont think java.util.Date is depricated..

Comment: You are right, `Date(String)` is deprecated, not `Date(long)`.

Comment: ok, and how to convert this result to readable format, like 22.08.2016...?

Comment: For that we have the SimpleDateFormat right. asish's answer.