# How to android + sqlite + date + time?need date/time operations

Tags: java, android, sqlite, datetime

I have an activity where i want to to save some measures data into a sqlite database(i will have only insert option).The xml  is:

[image]

date / time is taking value(by date/time dialogs) after the create of this activity,then user can change it if he wants.

I want in another activity to have listview of measures by descending date + time.

I want also to be able to fetch the measures of last 1 / 7 / 30 days.

What is the best way to make the sqlite table?How i should save date + time?together?or not?as TEXT or REAL or INTEGER so that can i easily make the above operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `System.currentTimeMillis()` and store that BIGINT value in the table.  You can parse the time with something like this:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd,yyyy HH:mm");

    Date resultdate = new Date(yourmilliseconds);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(resultdate));
```

Source: [How to transform currentTimeMillis to a readable date format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364383/android-how-to-get-currenttimemillis-to-datetime-format)

Comment: I want also to be able to fetch the measures of last 1 / 7 / 30 days        How i could do that with this way?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you, this will give you the current date and time of the device.  If you want to create a Date object, there is documentation online for that.