# Time format with java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to transform currentTimeMillis to a readable date format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364383/how-to-transform-currenttimemillis-to-a-readable-date-format)

This is my code:

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
final String appTime1 = Long.toString(currentTime);
```

it display the time as 1353929203337

Please i ask how can change the first format of time to this format 10:25:24 ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Date date = new Date(currentTime); // if U really have long
Strint result = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(date.getTime());
```

Comment: Sure, but user1735757 have started with long, I wasn't sure what exactly he needs. My approach just converts to String whaat he had as incoming parameter.

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR The `Date` constructor that takes a `long` is not deprecated; see the API documentation.

Comment: @Jesper oops, my bad. +1, guess i was just confused :P

Comment: @Romczyk: please i ask if its possible to have also millisecondes and nanosecondes here new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss") ? Thank you for answer

Comment: Milliseconds yes: ("HH:mm:ss:SSS")
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
But I am not sure, how it's best can be done to get nanoseconds printed: you can try ("HH:mm:ss:SSSSSS") out

Comment: And yes, as other users have stated, using Calendar would be a better approach

Answer (score 0):

That's right, it's showing the time in milliseconds dating back from 1st January 1970. Use `SimpleDateFormat` to format the date.

Try this code:

```
public class DateChk {


    public static void main(String[] args){

        DateChk chk = new DateChk();
        String s = chk.getCaptureDate();

        System.out.println(s);

    }

    public String getCaptureDate() {


        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        String dateTime = sdf.format(System.currentTimeMillis()); // Your Answer
        return dateTime;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends for what you need it for:
For simple debugging output the simplest is:

```
 final String appTime1 = new Date(currentTime).toString();
```

For more serius time calculations you better use `Calendar`.

Answer (score -1):

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

will get you the number of milliseconds since some date in the 70's.

If you want the current time you need to use a Calendar class and retrieve the time out of there using SimpleDateFormat.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println( sdf.format(cal.getTime()) );
```