# How to get readable time from currentTimeMillis()

Tags: java, time

So below there's a simple way to get a readout from current time millis, but how do I get from my millisecond value to a readable time? Would I be just a stack of modulus that are dividing incrementally by 60? (exception being 100 milliseconds to a second)

Would I be right in thinking/doing that?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give

```
  public class DisplayTime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.print("Current time in milliseconds = ");
                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());


        }
    }
```

Comment: That gives you a `long` value. Use it with `java.util.Calendar`, by setting the time in milliseconds. Also then use a `DateFormat` to print it the way you want.

Comment: The usual knee-jerk-reflex answer has always been "use the Joda Time library."  I'm surprised I don't see it yet.

Answer (score 12):

You may try like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364383/how-to-transform-currenttimemillis-to-a-readable-date-format):-

```
    long yourmilliseconds = 1119193190;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm");

    Date resultdate = new Date(yourmilliseconds);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(resultdate));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use that value with a `Calendar` object

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

String date = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-"+c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"-"+c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
String time = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+":"+c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

System.out.println(date + " " + time);
```

Output:

```
2013-8-21 16:27:31
```

**Note:** `c.getInstance()` already holds the current datetime, so the second line is redundant. I added it to show how to set the time in millis to the `Calendar` object

Comment: Maybe worth noting that the second line is redundant - getInstance already returns the current time.

Comment: @assylias Yes but the OP wants to transform that long in a readable date, so the second line shows how to do it. I will update my answer

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.println(new java.util.Date());
```

is the same as

```
System.out.println(new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

bothe represent the current time in a readable format