# how can i display current time in java using currentTimeMillis() method

Tags: java, methods

i want to create a java program that displays the current time in GMT timezone using `System.currentTimeMillis()` method.

```
public class DisplayTime {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        long totalMilliSeconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long totalSeconds = totalMilliSeconds / 1000;
        long currentSecond = totalSeconds % 60;
        long totalMinutes = totalSeconds / 60;
        long currentMinute = totalMinutes % 60;
        long totalHours = totalMinutes / 60;
        long currentHour = totalMinutes % 12;
        System.out.println(currentHour + " : " + currentMinute + " : " + currentSecond);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your code? s.o. can help if you show some efforts!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to transform currentTimeMillis to a readable date format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364383/how-to-transform-currenttimemillis-to-a-readable-date-format)

Comment: The easiest is `Instant.ofEpochMilli()`. Its `toString()` will give you an acceptable format, or you may format it to your liking. Don't know if it counts as cheating.

Comment: Does the code you have do as you want? In what way not?

Comment: Looks like it should work except `long currentHour = totalMinutes % 12` needs to use `totalHours` instead of `totalMinutes`

Comment: thanks BarrySW19, it works

Answer (score 0):

I think this was answered on this post:[How to transform currentTimeMillis to a readable date format? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364383/how-to-transform-currenttimemillis-to-a-readable-date-format)